# Add key events to react Projects

Tags: reactjs, keyboard-shortcuts

Following is my sample code:

```
Class School extends React.Componenet {
  deleteStudent = () => {
    // Logic of delete student goes here.
  }
  openNewForm = () => {
    // Logic of new form goes here.
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
         <div>
           /* Here goes my view part */
         </div>
         <div>
           <Button onClick={this.deleteStudent}/>
           <BUtton onClick={this.openNewForm}/>
         </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to add keyboard events on my react projects. Suppose If I will press the delete button from keyboard then it will delete the selected student. If will press the 'N' key then it will execute open new form events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this :

```
detectUserKey(event) {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
       //do something
    }
    else {
       //do default
    }
}
```

on the component you can do something like :

```
onKeyDown={e => this.detectUserKey(e)}
onKeyPress={e => this.detectUserKey(e)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the KeyboardEvents for this. Using the keyboardEventHandler(like onKeyPress, onKeyDown, onKeyUp) you can get which key is pressed in the keyboard. Here,

```
if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == KeyCodes.KEY_DELETE) {
//do your respective action
}
```

condition check can be added to know which key is pressed.